# React and simple UI state

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, state

I'm starting to playing around with React and have a basic question regarding state.

I understand that in React state should only contain data which may change and cannot be computed from elsewhere, however what about simple UI state that is not determined from any particular data and does not need to persist long-term?

For example, I have a mobile menu which is collapsible on small screens via CSS. The initial state of this menu is closed, and a simple `onClick` handler is attached to the toggle button. Inside the handler I can either:

1) use `getDOMNode` and `classList.toggle` on the element;

2) include this as a state property, then call `setState` to trigger a re-render.

The second option appears to me like the React way, but overkill especially on an app with potentially lots of menus, drop-downs etc. What is the best pattern for handling this kind of basic UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that in React state should only contain data which may
>   change and cannot be computed from elsewhere,

I think there is no need to store something that cannot change in a variable at all (use constants for that). And if something can be computed from elsewhere, you might wrap calculation into a function and call it when you need. So, this applies not to React component's state, but to a more wider scope of problems.

> however what about simple UI state that is not determined from any
>   particular data and does not need to persist long-term?

My opinion is that React component's state should contain everything, that affects the presentation of your component at any point in time.

> For example, I have a mobile menu which is collapsible on small
>   screens via CSS. The initial state of this menu is closed, and a
>   simple onClick handler is attached to the toggle button.

Your `onClick` should do one of the following:

- **Long way**: Send a message via an action to a datastore about user action. Datastore will consider the situation (can user click the item or not, for example) and will send state information into a components (using action or by `trigger`ing datastore (in [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs)). Component will modify its state using datastore information by calling `setState` (and rerendering afterwards).
- **Short way**: call setState directly from your `onClick` handler.

In both cases component's `state` should definitely include the `collapsed` field (or whatever other field, affecting how the component is rendered).

Another important consideration: React philosophy (my point of view) disregards DOM modifications outside `render()` calls. Of course you can use jQuery from render() to modify components, but... this may soon cause problems if jQuery starts modifying something, that was just rendered by React.

It is always better not to touch DOM rendered by React outside `render()`.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my thoughts. In the end I made a generic `MenuToggle` event / datastore so there's actually little boilerplate code when I add more.

Comment: @Graham Ok ;) Glad you solved that one.